# How is the generic-type hash calculated?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

When returning a generic type in a WCF service, the service client generation will generate a type with the name "[GenericType]Of[TypeParameterName][hash]".

According to this [Data Contract Names MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx) the hash is generated by the name of the type parameter name, and the namespace of it. But I wonder, how exactly is this hash value calculated?

The document only states the following:

> A hash is the result of a mathematical function that acts as a "fingerprint" that uniquely identifies a piece of data. When all of the generic parameters are primitive types, the hash is omitted.

Comment: Most likely this is not explicitly defined, because they reserve the right to change the hashing function at any time. It may be dangerous to rely on a specific hashing function being used.

Comment: Implementation detail.   Why do you want to know?

Comment: I want to write an own service client generation tool, because the Microsoft one is way too verbose. No need for all these .xsd and .datasource files that are generated. And I want the resulting code to be exactly as the one generated from Microsoft.

Comment: Oh, and it also just interests me. :)